# Move point data to the nearest polygon

Tags: polygon, point, alignment, footprint, move

I have two datasets, one is building footprint dataset and another is point data.

In my database some points are not within the building footprints and some points are scattered on the roads. I want the entire point data to be aligned in the footprint. There is no link for the two datasets to join the data. How can I move the points in to the nearest polygon without manual efforts. I'm using both ArcGIS and QGIS software.

Screenshot for quick reference:

[image]

Comment: Using what GIS software?

Comment: I am working on both qgis and arcgis softwares

Comment: There will be separate questions for arcgis and qgis. Kindly ask for a specific one.

Comment: Without some sort of attribute link between the point and the *correct* building footprint there is no way to ensure that a point will be moved to the *polygon that the point represents*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PyQGIS. This will modify the layer inplace, to back it up first.

```py
#Create layer objects from layernames
pointlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("pointstomove")[0]
polylayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("building")[0]

polygons = [f.geometry() for f in polylayer.getFeatures()] #List all polygons
newgeoms = {} #A dictionary to store each point id and the new position of it, 
#  for all points that should be moved

for f in pointlayer.getFeatures(): #For each point
    g = f.geometry() #Fetch its geometry
    distances = [g.distance(p) for p in polygons] #List the distances from it to each polygon
    if 0 not in distances: #If the distance to any of them isnt 0, the point is outside
        ix = distances.index(min(distances)) #Index of the polygon nearest to the point
        nearest_poly = polygons[ix] #Fetch the polygon geometry by the index
        centerpoint = nearest_poly.pointOnSurface() #Create a new point inside it
        newgeoms[f.id()]=centerpoint #Store point id and new point in the dict

pointlayer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues(newgeoms) #Apply changes
```

[image]

Comment: Can we arrange the points in any pattern within the polygon ????

Comment: Nice. You can place it randomly with `centerpoint = nearest_poly.randomPointsInPolygon(1)`. A regular pattern is more difficult

Comment: how can i apply this expression

Comment: Change `centerpoint = nearest_poly.pointOnSurface()` line to `centerpoint = nearest_poly.randomPointsInPolygon(1)`

Comment: can you please elaborate as i am new to qgis

Comment: where to apply the query, in python console or field calculator or expression???

Comment: In my original answer, in the code that move the points to inside the polygons

Comment: yes the script works. Points moved in side the polygon

Comment: centerpoint = nearest_poly.pointOnSurface() line to centerpoint = nearest_poly.randomPointsInPolygon(1)     How can i use this???